# perl cgi how to store/send data entered by user in dynamic table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, perl, cgi

After reading few threads from this forum , i was able to create a CGI page , with dynamic table in it. Now i need to capture the information entered in the table and store it in backend ( I am planning to store into db ).

Can someone please show me how do it . I heard that it can be done using jquery and AJAX. But i am new to web technology and stuck not knowing how to proceed with them.

**NOTE**: as I mentioned its a dynamic table. User add/delete rows as many as he wants. I need to capture all those data.

This is what i have tried so far

**Perl CGI script**

```
#!C:\Program Files\Perl\bin\perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw{ :standard };
use CGI::Carp qw{ fatalsToBrowser };
print_page_header();
print_html_head_section();


#################
## Subroutines ##
#################
sub print_page_header {
    print "Content-type:  text/html\n\n";
}


sub print_html_head_section {
    print "<head>\n";
    print "<title>sample test page</title>\n";
    print "<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'  type='text/javascript'></script>\n";
     print "<script src='../js/mastertable_rowcontrol.js'  type='text/javascript'></script>\n";
    #print qq{
    #       <script>
    #       function myFunction() {
    #       var table=document.getElementById("master_table");
    #       for (var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++) {
    #       alert(table.rows.[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
    #       }
    #       }
    #       </script>
    #       };
    print "</head>\n";
}

print qq{
     <table id="master_table" border="0">
     <tr>
     <th>COL1</th>
     <th>COL2</th>
     <th>COL3</th>
     <th>COL4</th>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <input type="text" name="col1" class="col1"/>
     </td>
         <td>
     <input type="text" name="col2" class="col2"/>
     </td>
         <td>
     <input type="text" name="col3" class="col3"/>
     </td>
         <td>
     <input type="text" name="col4" class="col4"/>
     </td>
         <td>
     <input type="button" name="addRow" class="add" value='Add'/>
     </td>
         <td>
     <input type="button" name="removeRow" class="removeRow" value='Delete'/>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td colspan="4" align="center">
     <input type="button" name="submit_data" class="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()"/>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     };
```

**jquery used to create dynamic table**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click','#master_table .add',function () {

       var row=$(this).closest('tr');
       var clone = row.clone();
       var tr= clone.closest('tr');
       tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');
       $(this).closest('tr').after(clone);
       var $span=$("#master_table tr");
       $span.attr('id',function (index) {
       return 'span' + index;
});
  });

  $(document).on('click','#master_table .removeRow',function () {
      if ($('#master_table .add').length > 1) {
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: So you're having the use build the table of data on the client side, then you wan to submit all the table data to the server for storage?

Comment: Thats right. I also got a suggestion that if i can keep the cell ids as unique then i can easily extract column info from the table and pass it on. But i am also not sure how to set unique id to cells

Comment: have you written any CGI scripts yet? one the displays the contents of %ENV is a good start.  The do one that accepts a parameter called name, and prints it to the screen as part of the html page.  You have to start at first principles. before you roller skate, you have to crawl.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you built a dynamic-table using HTML, and have it submit the user-input to a Perl script for further processing or assorting, as needed.

Just design a HTML Form that looks like a table (you can use most of the code you have already written). To submit it to the perl script, you need to do this:

```
<form action="/somefolder/yourperlscript.pl" method="POST">

<!-- Your Table here -->

</form>
```

You may remember, that in linux the location of your file should begin with "/somefolder/yourscript.pl" while on windows, it should be with the slash in the beginning  "somefolder/yourscript.pl